# Comparison between numerical solution of nonlinear ode and nonlinear ode of second order

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, modeling

#### Background

Let's consider the following initial value problem for nonlinear system
$$
\begin{cases}
E' &=& 1 - n_e, \\
n_e' &=& -8\,n_e\,E,
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$
with the following initial conditions
$$
n_e(0) = 0.999,\quad E(0) = 4\cdot10^{-4}.
\tag{2}
$$
**WM** code is as follows:

```
L = 6;
a = -8;
{ne, Ef} = NDSolveValue[{Ef'[x] == 1 - ne[x],ne'[x] == a ne[x] Ef[x], 
Ef[0] == 4 10^-4, ne[0] == 0.9999},
{ne, Ef}, {x, 0, L}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Plot[{ne[x], Ef[x]}, {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400]
```

Plot of numerical solution of (1), (2) to be the following:
[image: Numerical solution of (1), (2)]

Also, one could express $E$ from (2):
$$
E = -\frac{n'_e}{8n_e}
\tag{3}
$$
and substitute (3) in (1):
$$
-\biggl(\frac{n'_e}{8n_e}\biggr)' = 1 - n_e.
\tag{4}
$$
Then, nonlinear equation is arised:
$$
n''_e - \dfrac{(n'_e)^2}{n_e} = -8(1 - n_e)n_e.
\tag{5}
$$
Now, boundary conditions are the following
$$
n_e(0) = 0.999,\quad n_e(6) = 0.
\tag{6}
$$
**WM** code:

```
sol01 = NDSolveValue[{ne''[x] - 1/ne[x] (ne'[x])^2 == -8 (1 - ne[x]) ne[x], 
ne[0] == 0.999, ne[6] == 0}, ne, {x, 0, 6}]
```

**Output** is as follows:

[image]

#### Question

So, my question wether it is possible to find similar numerical solution of (5),(6) to numerical solution of (1),(2) or not?

#### Notice

One could also find the following substitution
$$
\varphi = \ln{n_e},~n_e = \exp{\varphi}.
\tag{7}
$$
So, (5) transforms into (8)
$$
\varphi'' = -8(1 - \exp{\varphi}).
\tag{8}
$$
The question expand on (8) as well.

UPD1. Misprints in (5) fixed.

Comment: Well, your `(3)` is valid  iff `ne != 0` ...

Comment: Fore sure. That is a question how to find a suitable analog...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solve here the 3D equation

$$\nabla ^2\phi =-8 (1-\exp (\phi ))$$

in the special case of spherical symmetry, and compare the numerical solution with the exact soluton of the linearized problem.
We leave a possible derivation of this equation in the 3D case to the author of the OP.

The equation to be solved is in Mathematica notation

```
eq3 = u''[r] + 2/r u'[r] == 8 (Exp[u[r]] - 1);
```

To simplify the typesetting in Mathematica we formulate the equation in terms of `u[r]` instead of `\[Phi][r].`

In analogy to the 1D case we shall also consider the quantity

```
n[r_] = Exp[u[r]];
```

*Numerical solution*

The numerical solution must be accompanied by two boundary conditions. 
It seems natural to let `u'[0] == 0` and `u[0] == u30`, a small negative number taken from the 1D case.
In the numerical treatment we have to replace 0 by some small number, say `r0 = 0.001`.

```
u30 = Log[0.999]

(* Out[86]= -0.0010005 *)

uu[r_] = u[r] /. 
    NDSolve[{eq3, u[0.001] == u30, u'[0.001] == 0}, u[r], {r, 0, 8}] // Quiet;

n3 = Exp[uu[r]];
```

*Exact solution of the linearized equation*

The linearized equation is

```
eq3L = u3L''[r] + 2/r u3L'[r] == 8 u3L[r];
```

Its solution is

```
uu3L = u3L[r] /. DSolve[eq3L && u3L[0] == u3L0, u3L[r], r][[1]]

(*
Out[92]= (E^(-2 Sqrt[2] r) (-1 + E^(4 Sqrt[2] r)) u3L0)/(4 Sqrt[2] r)
*)
```

It is interesting that the finiteness at `r = 0` alone already takes care for the condition `u'[0]==0`.

Indeed

```
Series[((E^(-2 Sqrt[2] r)) (-1 + E^(4 Sqrt[2] r)) )/(4 Sqrt[2] r), {r, 0, 2}]//Normal

(*
Out[108]= 1 + (4 r^2)/3
*)
```

Now, for comparison, we let

```
u3L0 = u30;

n3L = Exp[uu3L];
```

and plot both solutions together

```
Plot[{n3, n3L}, {r, 0, 6}, AxesLabel -> {"r", "n3, n3L"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Solution of 3D eqution in spherical symmetry\nnumerical solution -> n = \
blue\nlinear approximation -> n = yellow"]
```

[image]

*Additional remarks*

The same comparison can be made for the 1D case with the result

[image]

In the 1D case you get a good overview over the solution using StreamPlot[]:

```
StreamPlot[{- 8 fE n, 1 - n}, {n, -1, 3}, {fE, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "ODEs E' = 1 - n, n' = - 8 E n\nStreamplot of dE/dn", 
 AxesLabel -> {"n", "E"}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

The explicit for of the streamlines (orbits) are easily obtained exactly by solving  `8 dE/dn = (1-n)/(E n)` to give

```
fE = {Sqrt[c + n - Log[n]], -Sqrt[c + n - Log[n]]};
```

with an integration constant `c`.

The separatrix is given by c = -1.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dr. Wolfgang! Let me also ask about nonsymmetrical case. Suppose, that we consider 3D cartesian $\varphi=\varphi(x,y,z)$
$$
\nabla^2 \equiv \partial_x + \partial_y + \partial_z.
\tag{$\ast$}
$$
How should we solve BVP (or IVP) of 
$$
\nabla^2 \varphi = -8 (1 - \exp(\varphi))
$$
 to obtain ''hat'' like solution?

Comment: @olekravchenko: some remarks: 1) what are the boundary conditions for your partial differental equation in (x,y,z)? 2) I suggest to consider the linear approximation first, as it is a classical case, where all solution methods are well known. 3) In the extremely nonlinear case where you drop the 1, for 1D you get the solution Log[E^A*Sec[(Sqrt[E^A]*x)/Sqrt[2]]^2];which shows a periodic divergence in a the points xn = pi Sqrt(2) Exp(-A) (n+1/2), n integer.

Comment: 1) well, that is the question I've asked in the very beginning, even in 1D case I still have no idea about coressponding BVP with numerical solution like in IVP (1), (2). For example, in 2D I expect somewhat like "hat" function which one could obtain by rotation of $n_3(x^2+y^2)$ solution. In 3D I also expect somewhat like a "semi-hat" solution.
So, BC in 2D to be like that:
$$
\left.\varphi(x,y)\right|_{x=0} = n_3(y),\,
\left.\varphi(x,y)\right|_{y=0} = n_3(x),\,
\left.\varphi(x,y)\right|_{x=L} = n_3(L),\,
\left.\varphi(x,y)\right|_{y=L} = n_3(L).
$$

Comment: @olekravchenko: the answer to your preliminary question is "no", as belisarius already said. You can't have n(0) = n0 with n !=0 and n(x0) = 0 for any finite x0. It is exactly the region of small phi for which the linearization is valid, and you can study the approach to 0. I don't understand what you mean by "hat" function. I have shown how to solve the 3D symmetric case. You can do the 2D symmetric case similarly by yourself. Also, as I said, in the linear approximation you can easily get the results for any reasonable boundary conditions using the standard procedures (separation of vars.)

Comment: $\text{@Dr.WolfgangHintze}:$ thank you for your answer! I mean "hat", cause the considered are is a quoter of a square with center point in $(0;0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Equation (4) should read `ne''[x] - ne'[x]^2/ne[x] == -8 (1 - ne[x]) ne[x]`.  Additionally, boundary conditions derived from the original equations are `ne[0] == 0.999, ne'[0] == -32*^-4 ne[0]`  With these changes,

```
sol01 = NDSolveValue[{ne''[x] - ne'[x]^2/ne[x] == -8 (1 - ne[x]) ne[x], ne[0] == 0.999, 
    ne'[0] == -32*^-4 ne[0]}, ne, {x, 0, 6}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Plot[sol01[x], {x, 0, 6}, AxesLabel -> {x, ne}]
```

[image]

gives the desired answer.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the fruitful comment. Definitely yes, it's an answer. But, if fact we solve IVP for $n_e$, don't we? What about corresponding BVP? Is it possible to find suitable BVP which gives the similar numerical solution as IVP, isn't it?

Comment: What about multidimensional case? For example,
let's consider
$$
\nabla^2 \varphi = -8 (1 - \exp(\varphi)).
\tag{$\ast$}
$$
Should we consider IVP problem for $(\ast)$ instead of BVP, shouldn't we?

Comment: @olekravchenko  To solve the 2nd order ODE requires an appropriate boundary condition at `x = 6`.  `ne[6] == 0` is not the right choice, because it leads to `ne = 0` everywhere, which is inconsistent with `ne[0] == .999`.  You should pose your PDE as a separate question, because it is well beyond the scope of the present question.